# How can I prevent data duplication in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table in database SQL SERVER 2005 that looks like this:

```
UserId     ProductId        ProductName
 1         2                ABC
 1         2                ABC
```

Now I want to apply check so that the same productId cannot be entered again for same user. I also want sql server to enforce this check.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be more nature to declare primary key (UserId, ProductId) instead of using check statement

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933092(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?:

Before creating your new key, clean up the duplicates:

See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

And once you are done with that, you can execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD CONSTRAINT pk_UserIdProductId PRIMARY KEY (UserId, ProductId)
```

Of course, if you just illustrated an example and don't have any duplicates yet, just try the command above out.